# Spring XD: stream and source are inbound/outbound channel adapters?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-cloud-dataflow

The **source component** in Spring XD is designed always like a **inbound channel adapter** by Spring Integration?

Same question about **sink component**: is always designes like **outbound channel adapter**?

In the doc [here about the sink](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#creating-a-sink-module) and here [about the source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#creating-a-source-module) i read only about these adapters, but it's not clear for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, but it's not required - anything that can create a spring-messaging `Message<?>` can be a source, and anything that can accept one can be a sink.

Comment: Tnx for the answer! But are always Spring Integration component?